# Minimizaiton of $f\mapsto\int\frac12\|f\|^2+\nabla\cdot f\:{\rm d}\mu$, when $\mu$ is only given by i.i.d. samples

Tags: optimization, markov-chains, machine-learning, numerical-optimization, monte-carlo

I know this question is quite vague, but I need some indication. I have a problem where I have a probability distribution $\mu$ on $\mathbb R^d$ and I want to find a differentiable function $f:\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R^d$ minimizing $$F(f):=\int\frac12\|f\|^2+\nabla\cdot f\:{\rm d}\mu$$ (the divergence is applied componentwisely). I only need to know $f$ on a finite grid $G\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ of equidistant points. It can be assumed that $\mu$ is only supported on the bounding box of this grid. I cannot sample from $\mu$, since it is unknown to me. I only have i.i.d. samples from it.

How is such a problem usually solved? I guess it will be important to fix a function space (Banach space) on which I formally define $F$ for the minimization.

Gradient descent cannot be applied here (due to the unavailability of $\mu$), but maybe "stochastic" gradient descent? I've actually never touched that topic before (though I'm completely familiar with MCMC and stochastic analysis; so it should be easy to understand for me. However, I only find articles which seem to be written for practitioners and it's for some reason hard to understand for me as someone, which is used to work more mathematically rigorous).

Any advice is highly appreciated!

Comment: For $\varphi\in C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R}^d)$ you can calculate $0=d_t F(f+t\varphi)|_{t=0}$, which gives you for all such $\varphi$ the equality $\int \nabla\cdot \varphi\, d\mu = -\int \langle f,\varphi\rangle\, d\mu$. This means, that $f$ is the distributional derivative of $\mu$. Not sure if it helps, though.

Comment: Assuming $\mu$ has a density $p$ and $f$ is not constrained, then a heuristic computation using Euler–Lagrange equation tells that $F$ is minimized by the (Stein) score function $$\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})=\nabla_{\mathbf{x}}\log p(\mathbf{x}).$$ This is not surprising, since minimizing $F$ is often called **implicit score matching** in the machine learning literature. (See [Hyvärinen (2005)](https://jmlr.org/papers/v6/hyvarinen05a.html), for instance.) There are various techniques to estimate $f$ from i.i.d. samples of $\mu$ under the umbrella term "score matching".

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you for your comment. Yes, I've seen the "score matching" papers. Sliced score matching, denoising score matching and so on. But they only give the objective function (as in my post above) without clarifying (at least for me) how the actual minimization is performed. Yes, by some kind of "neural network". But I'm not familiar with that. How can I understand this (in a sense, which makes me capable to implement this stuff) without reading one of the thousand articles on neural networks, which seem to be totally unrelated to my specific optimization problem?

Comment: @humanStampedist +1. Thanks for your comment. Yeah, I already came up with that as well, but it didn't seem to reduce the problem; but maybe it does?

Comment: @SangchulLee I also wonder whether a Bismut-Elworthy-Li-type formula could help to find your $p$, assuming it is the density of a SDE solution at a fixed time.

Comment: The problem is a bit unclear. Assume that the function $f$is given by $c^Tx$. Could you clearly write down the objective based on the sample you have?

Comment: Usually the training is done by fixing the class of functions $f$ can assume (via a suitable parametrization $f=f_{\theta}$) and then replacing the true data distribution $\mu$ by the empirical distribution $\hat{\mu}=\frac{1}{|\mathcal{D}|}\sum_{x\in\mathcal{D}}\delta_{x}$ in the objective function. The resulting objective function $$F(\theta)=\frac{1}{|\mathcal{D}|}\sum_{x\in\mathcal{D}}\left(\frac{1}{2}\|f_{\theta}(x)\|^2+(\nabla\cdot f_{\theta})_{x}\right)$$ is now a real-valued function of $\theta$ and hence we can apply whatever optimization technique as we want.

Comment: Of course, this transition from $\mu$ to $\hat{\mu}$ may induce undesirable effects, such as the learned score being overly mimicking the empirical distribution instead of generalizing to the (unknown) data distribution. (See [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/2401.04856), for example.) I don't know much about how this problem is resolved in practice.

Comment: As for your second comment, I am not sure if I know anything about "Bismut-Elworthy-Li-type formula", except that it deals with the derivative of a solution of SDE with respect to its initial condition.

Comment: @SangchulLee Do you have an example of such a parametrization at hand? I cannot imagine anything. What is $\theta$? The only plausible thing which would came to my mind is $\theta\in H^1$ (Sobolev space) and $f_\theta=\theta$, but that's is clearly not what you intend ...

Comment: If you need a purely mathematical answer, you actually don't need parametrization in order to define the minimization objective and find its minimizers. On the other hand, when you want to implement it as a computer algorithm that utilizes optimization techniques, you need to further restrict the function space to a finite-dimensional submanifold. This is where the parametrization kicks in. $f=f_{\theta}$ is in fact an embedding $\mathbb{R}^d\ni \theta\mapsto f_{\theta}$, which then allows us to rewrite the objective function $F$ in the form $\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Since the choice of submanifold affects how close the minimizers of $F(\theta)$ are to the actual minimizers of $F$, the choice of $f_{\theta}$ is often based on the specific problem you want to solve and designed to reflect the inductive bias towards generalizability. For example, in [Stable Diffusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_Diffusion), $f_{\theta}$ is designed using a time-conditional U-Net with a cross-attention conditioning mechanism. This allows $f_{\theta}$ to better reflect the structure of image data, compared to a mere feedforward neural network.